# Need help evaluating this improper double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Need help evaluating this improper integral
>   $$\iint_D (1-x+y)e^{(-2x+y)}\,dx\,dy$$
>   where $D$ is the region: $0 \le y  \le x $.

I've tried doing the substitution:

$u = -2x +y \\ v = 1-x+y$

which gives us the integral
$\iint_E ve^{u}\,du\,dv$ over the new region $E$.

To find the bounds for the intregral, I tried plugging in the values of $x$ and $y$ expressed in terms of  $u $ and $v$ so I get the inequality:
$$0 \le 2v-u-2\le -u-1+v  \le n$$ where $n$ tends to $\infty$.

But I'm not really sure how to interpret that inequality and find the bounds for the integral.

Comment: I think  x∈[0,∞)

Comment: So the Jacobian of your variable transformation is $1$?

Comment: Yes, thats what i got.

Comment: It usually helps if you plot the region in question. Since it's a couple of linear inequalities, it should be easy enough. You can even do it online, for example in Desmos graphing calculator. Use some finite but large $n$

Comment: Note that you get three linear equations for the boundaries, so in general you are integrating over a triangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good method : looking for a domain which is a product $A \times B$.

The idea here is to make a change of variable keeping $y \in A=[0,+\infty)$ and introducing $z=x-y$.

$z$ is "the offset" from $x$ to $y$, naturally $\geq 0$ ; $z$ varies in the whole domain $B=[0,+\infty)$.

The integral becomes (due to a unit jacobian) :

$$\iint_{(y,z)\in A \times B} (1-z)e^{(-y-2z)}dydz=\iint_{A \times B} e^{(-y-2z)}dydz-\iint_{A \times B} ze^{(-y-2z)}dydz$$

that you can split into one-dimensional easily computable integrals.